# gsutil is stuck without copying any data

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am trying to upload files from compute engine instance  (debian) to cloud storage.
at some point gsutil completely stopped working. When running it with -D flag I see those replies:

reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n'header: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8header: Content-Encoding: gzipheader: Date: Tue, 27 May 2014 21:09:47 GMTheader: Expires: Tue, 27 May 2014 21:09:47 GMTheader: Cache-Control: private, max-age=0header: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniffheader: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGINheader: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=blockheader: Server: GSEheader: Alternate-Protocol: 443:quicheader: Transfer-Encoding: chunkedprocess count: 1thread count: 10

Comment: This is due to a bug in the gsutil 4.0 sends fields for parallel composite uploads when validating existing parallel upload components, and should likely be fixed in an upcoming bugfix release.  Until then you can use the workaround I suggested below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting parallel_composite_upload_threshold = 0 under the [GSUtil] section in your boto file.